# SQL Server 2008 Declaring and setting variables using columns from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables

I need help with declaring a variable in SQL Server. This variable is supposed to be an int that is calculated with the values from each row for the columns of `dblelectrodelength` and `dblelectrodespacing`. How would I go about doing this?

```
Declare @T0 int = ((dblelectrodelength - 1) +  0 * (dblelectrodespacing + dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2))
```

Comment: Use a subquery `DECLARE... = (SELECT col + col)` etc.  Keep in mind, variables only hold a single value.  It seems like you may be intending to calculate this across multiple rows, which would only work in a loop with this approach (there are better approaches if that is the case, but we need more info).

Comment: I know this SQL and all, but my recollection is that 0*anything=0. :)

Comment: Integer Variables hold ***single*** values *(scalars)*.  You appear to want to put a whole ***set*** of values in to a variable.  Do you mean that you want a table with an integer column *(possibly a table variable)*?  The best suggestion I can make is to provide a bit more information; what are you going to ***do*** with this?  Show us from beginning to end what you want; some sample data, the processing you want to do, and the results that you want at the end.  This, so far, is too abstract, with an inherent misunderstanding/inconsistency...

Answer (score 1):

A variable holds a single value, you need multiple values (one for each row). You can then use a table variable:

```
Declare @T0 table (value int);
insert into @T0 (value)
select ( (dblelectrodelength-1) + (dblelectrodelength/2) )
from myTable;
```

Note: Removed the unnecessary  + 0*(...) part.